# Ignoring curly braces in search

Tags: latex, search, isearch, bibtex, fuzzy-search

Journal article titles in my BibTeX appear as follows:

```
Title="{{E}nsure {C}onsistence {C}apitalization in {T}itles}",
```

This produces consistence output, which I am happy with. However, searching for title text in this file is very difficult.

Is it possible to "ignore" curly braces in a (case-insensitive) search pattern, such that I can simply search for the title of an article, without concerning myself with the curly braces?

Comment: Did you try matching with a regexp: `C-M-s`? If so, in what way doesn't that work for you here?

Comment: I would like a general solution to search for any title of interest, regardless of where the curly braces would be.

Comment: This may be helpful? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lax-Search.html

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlexIsearch  "This is a minor mode that modifies isearch-mode. If the search fails, the search string is transformed into a regular expression that matches the original and similar strings."